# Is the md5 function safe to use for merging datasets?

Tags: sas, md5

We are about to promote a piece of code which uses the SAS `md5()` hash function to efficiently track changes in a large dataset.

```
format md5 $hex32.;
md5=md5(cats(of _all_));
```

As per the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003064419.htm):

> The MD5 function converts a string, based on the MD5 algorithm, into a 128-bit hash value. This hash value is referred to as a message digest (digital signature), which is nearly unique for each string that is passed to the function.

At approximately what stage does 'nearly unique' begin to pose a data integrity risk (if at all)?

Comment: How much 'integrity' does your data require?  For example, sometimes a small loss of integrity will not affect the story the data tells.  If 2 different changes in your large dataset end up looking the same, will it *really* make a difference, or can you live with it? If you're working with clinical trials, accuracy sure would seem important.  If you're working with typical business reports (that don't link into the GL/accounting/PO's etc), md5 is probably good enough.

Comment: If you're dealing with clinical trials and have that sort of size of data that this is needed I'm impressed :)  But definitely what Rob says is highly relevant here.

Comment: It's for internal reporting..  I think (with @stig's delimiter suggestion) the risk is low enough that the efficiency gains are worth it, in this case.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen an example where the md5 comparison goes wrong.
If you have the values "AB" and "CD" in the (two columns of the) first row and "ABC" and "D" in the second row, they got the same md5 value. See this example:

```
data md5;
  attrib a b length=$3 informat=$3.;
  infile datalines;
  input a b;
  format md5 $hex32.;
  md5=md5(cats(of _all_));
datalines;
AB CD
A BCD
;run;
```

This is, of course, because the CATS(of _all_) will concatinate and strip the variables (converting numbers to string using the "best" format), without a delimiter. If you use CAT instead , this will not happen because the leading and trailing blanks are not removed. This error is not very far fetched. If you have missing values, then this could occur more often. If, for example, you have a lot of binary values in text variables, some of which are missing, it could occur very often.

One could do this manually, adding a delimiter in between the values. Of course, you would still have the case when you have ("AB!" and "CD") and ("AB" and "!CD") and you use "!" as delimiter...

Answer (score 2):

MD5 has 2^128 distinct values, and from what I've read at 2^64 different values (that's 10^20 or so) you begin to have a high likelihood of finding a collision.

However, as a result of how MD5 is generated, you have some risks of collisions from very similar preimages which only differ in as little as two bytes.  As such, it's hard to say how risky this would be for your particular process.  It's certainly *possible* for a collision to occur on as few as two messages.  It's not *likely*.  Does saving [some] computing time benefit you enough to outweigh a small risk?

Comment: This is an example of the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table). The table on that page shows that you would need 8.2*10^11 rows to have a 10^-15 chance of at least one collision. By the time you get to 10^20 rows the chance is over 50%.

Comment: Realising that my question was a bit vague..  Accepting Stig's on the basis of it being very practical advice.  +1 though, thanks..

Comment: In 9.4 Maintenance 1 or better there's SHA256(). It produces a 256-bit hash value.